# Unable to get user attributes in the cognitoUser object after authenticating using aws-amplify

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have an Angular 11 project in which I'm using AWS Amplify ([aws-amplify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-amplify) v3.3.26) and I'm using Cognito user pools to manage users. I've set up the hosted UI and I've not used any custom attributes. Everything is working and I've selected all the attributes for read and write permissions in the user attributes in the user pool.

I'm using the following code to get the cognitoUser object:-

```
Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
      .then((currentUser) => {
        console.log('The currentUser => ', currentUser);
      
        Auth.currentUserInfo()
          .then((res) => {
            console.log('Here are the current user info! =>', res);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log('Current user info failed to fetch', err);
          });
       
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    return;
  }
```

According to the [AWS Amplify docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/manageusers/q/platform/js#retrieve-attributes-for-current-authenticated-user) I should be able to get the attributes right within the cognitoUser object. But I'm not getting it.

This is all I get (also note that session is null, not sure what that means):-
[image]

As you can see there is no "attributes" key in the object.

I also noticed that there is a `Auth.currentUserInfo()` method that is available and my console log of that just results in an empty object.

And as you can see here, I have set all the required permissions for all the attributes in the user pool client definition and I don't have any custom attributes:-
[image]

Currently I am storing name and email as required attributes and all users have that. But I can't access it. I was able to see the email deeply nested within the cognitoUser object (`cognitoUser.signInUserSession.idToken.payload.email`) but still can't find the name attribute. I would like to get the entire attributes object listing all available attributes of the current user.

What am I missing?

Comment: Um, not sure what happened, but I messed around a bunch of things in the aws management console on the web and I think one of the things I did got it sorted out. Now I am receiving the attributes. I am not entirely sure, but it could be something to do with the identity pools? I'm sorry I can't pinpoint exactly what I did here, but I am now seeing the attributes key in the user object. :/

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue as well, `CognitoUser` was missing the `attributes` object.
The solution was to include the **aws.cognito.signin.user.admin** scope both on the client-side configuration and on the App Client Settings page in the User Pool settings.

The `oauth` configuration on the client side should look something like:

```
oauth: {
          domain: "https://your-cognito-domain",
          scope: ["phone", "email", "profile", "openid", "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin"],
          redirectSignIn: "https://yourdomain",
          redirectSignOut: "https://yourdomain",
          responseType: "code",
        },
```

The App Client settings in the AWS User Pool screen should have that enabled too.

[image: App Client Settings]

Answer (score 2):

I use this code below to get user attributes with the same version of Amplify.

```
const user = await Auth.currentUserInfo();
const userId = user.attributes.sub;
```

If user was not verified yet e.g by clicking on verification email link, or entering verification code, you will get empty object back from Auth.currentUserInfo.

But after user was verified, you can get all attributes with the exact same method. Either by using promise chain as in code below, or if you use async/await, just use the code above.

```
function getUserInfo(){
    return Auth.currentUserInfo()
          .then((res) => {
            console.log('Here are the current user info! =>', res);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log('Current user info failed to fetch', err);
          });
}
```

Comment: Yes, and this is the expected behavior, but for some reason I am not receiving the attributes key within the user object. I've tried both ways. You can see my console.log of the user object. It just doesn't have the "attributes". I don't know if I am supposed to do anything additional on the side of setting up the client or user pool or something on the aws console.

Comment: Can you post a sample of what the user object looks like for you? What keys it contains? And the general structure? And specifically if you have something called "Session" and what it contains? Does it have null, like it does for me or something else?